# Why cant you change UIButton image with animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a simple `UIButton` that i want to change its image with animation.
What happens is that it changes right a way, without delay or animation :

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                          delay:2.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{

                             [button setImage:darkCellimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

     }];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [fade between two UIButton images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801948/fade-between-two-uibutton-images)

Comment: no its not . that answer is not solving the real problem/question .

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, this is not possible. Hence the answer is "This can't be done" and the question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A button's image is not an animatable property, that's why you see an immediate application of a new value. Please see the list of animatable properties [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW2)

Comment: i have the same requirement. There must be a way

Comment: @AbdulYasin There is a way - implement your own UIButton subclass, provide a method for manual animated change of a button image (e.g. animate old image's alpha from 1 to 0, then replace the image with a new one, which has initial alpha 0, and then animate new image's alpha from 0 to 1). As an alternative, you may want to create a CALayer with animatable property, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/sc2284/Introduction/Intro.html